# When can I remove directory validation script?

Tags: directory, validation

When I apply to add my website to a directory, it asks to add some script to my homepage or index page to validate the website. At what point can I remove this script? I want to add my site to various directories, but don't want to add lines of script to be there permanently.
I'm assuming it is just for the initial validation and can be removed after submitting the site..?

Answer (score 1):

That's going to depend from site-to-site. Some only want to initially validate your site to make sure it is legitimate at the time of submission. Others will require it as they periodically check to maker sure your site is still there as they try to keep their directory fresh and prevent dead links.

Considering how little traffic and SEO value these directories offer, I wouldn't be concerned with removing them. I'd rather have a tidy site then a mess just to keep them happy.

Comment: Directories have little SEO value. Really...?

Comment: Yes Really, Google and other search engines have nuked the hell out of user generated content. What this is means is web directories, articles, profiles on forums etc are generated by the user and therefor can use used to manipulate search results, Google doesn't want Webmasters making links, it wants webmasters to focus on page SEO. The only web directories you should ever consider are niche directories, these still pass some authority if the site is well administrated with a no BS policy on who they link too.

Comment: Also, most web directories have duplicate content because the businesses or site owners use the same description on ever directory, so again.. Only ever consider a web directory that is a) Good, B) Specializes in your Niche with no other Niches C) Looks well administrated. D) No return link, a two way link is weakened because your returning the flow, enough 2 way links and your feel the wrath of Google, as they do no favor mass link exchanges.